# How to store multi-timezone system date?

Tags: php, mysql, timezone

### Question

I am building a web app that allow different timezone user to register. How we store the datetime over the database(mysql)? Store the datetime using ISO standard then convert it back to respective timezone over the sql request? Any idea?

### Expected Outcome

If user is from America, that user could see their record time based on USA time. If user is from Malaysia, they can see their record time based on Malaysia time.

### System Structure

- Php V 7.4
- Mysql

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do store the date values in MySQL using the provided data types, of course: typically `DATE` or `DATETIME`. Read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-types.html. This has nothing to do with ISO standard, since the value are stored internally as a binary format, not a string format.

Do not store dates as strings, because they take more space, and you increase the risk of storing invalid dates that can't be compared to others.

In almost every case, you should store all dates in UTC in the database. This allows you to do convenient things like compare events by timestamp or sort events by timestamp, regardless of the timezone of the user who created those events.

Allow users to have a preference to display times in their own local timezone, but do the timezone conversion during display, based on the canonical UTC values stored in the database.

This is general advice that will probably handle the cases you have in your typical software project. But as with anything in software design, there's an exception to every rule!

https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2019/03/27/storing-utc-is-not-a-silver-bullet/ is a blog written by famous Stack Overflow leader Jon Skeet. He explains in detail some edge cases where it's not always best to standardize on UTC.

It's up to you. Be mindful of general advice, and do follow that advice by default, unless you have a specific reason to part from that advice. But also be aware of exception cases, and the pros and cons of different approaches.

Comment: Bill, thanks for your comment. Appreciate that.  I found another post that is super useful, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28344550/how-to-handle-datetime-between-php-laravel-api-and-javascript-angularjs

Answer (score 0):

To summarize.

My solution is

1. Store datetime over mysql database, format is

> YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS

2. When return the data to frontend through api. Convert the datetime record to iso format first.

> Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s',
> $user->created_at)->toW3cString();

3. Then, when frontend receive the date, convert it using date library such as moment.

> correctTime = moment(apiDateTimeData).format(your preference time format);

Data Between Api and front end is look like this

> 2015-02-05T14:50:55+01:00

Reference Link:
[How to handle datetime between php (Laravel api) and javascript (AngularJS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28344550/how-to-handle-datetime-between-php-laravel-api-and-javascript-angularjs)

If you have any better solution, feel free to comment below nah.