# Format Laravel Timestamps in Front End with Javascript

Tags: javascript, laravel

I want to format the Laravel date format generated by timestamps, but I want to do that in the front end with Javascript, the time value is something like this `2022-01-03T19:16:16.000000Z`, so what I want to do is to format it to something like this: `02 Jan 2021`

Comment: You can use momentjs

Answer (score 2):

Here's a previous post on how you can accomplish this: [How to handle datetime between php (Laravel api) and javascript (AngularJS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28344550/how-to-handle-datetime-between-php-laravel-api-and-javascript-angularjs)

However, it's worth noting that Laravel handles this for you. See documentation on [Date Casting](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#date-casting).

```
/**
 * The attributes that should be cast.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $casts = [
    'created_at' => 'datetime:Y-m-d',
];
```

As the post suggests you can use momentjs:

```
correctTime = moment('<YOUR_UTC_TIME_STRING>').format();
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to format it in your frontend, you can use [carbon](https://carbon.nesbot.com/) to accomplish that task in your laravel backend, it is simple and straight forward

Comment: We prefer to send UTC timestamps to the front-end, and let it handle. Allows us to convert it into the browser's timezone automatically.

Comment: Oh okay got it, then it seems Kevin's answer will do